# AppEngine Pipelines - Rails alternative

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, google-app-engine, delayed-job, resque

I'm thinking of porting an [AppEngine](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/whatisgoogleappengine.html) application to [Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/), but I have a requirement that I can't find a solution for.

In my app, I use the [AppEngine Pipeline API](http://code.google.com/p/appengine-pipeline/) to essentially perform fan-in and run code after a large number of jobs have ran. I have found [Delayed::Job](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job) and [Resque](https://github.com/defunkt/resque), but those only seem useful for fan-out.

Is there a Rails alternatives to the Pipeline API?